# How to declare one variable for each row in trigger?

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I have following trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TIGGER_NAME   AFTER UPDATE ON MY_TABLE 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW  FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ( NEW.STATUS = ANY (10,40,42,44,46,50,60)  and OLD.STATUS != NEW.STATUS)        
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN   
  IF :NEW.ALERT is NULL  
  THEN      
    dbms_alert.signal('print_update_event','update_message');
  ELSE      
    dbms_alert.signal( :NEW.ALERT,'update_message');
  END IF;    
  commit;
END;
```

I would like to change it because it send alert for each row. I would like to send only one alert if more than one row with ALERT column equal NULL was updated and I would like to send one alert for each row with ALERT column NOT equal NULL.

As I understand Oracle variables I can declare local variable in my trigger but this variable will be declared separately for each row so following change has no sense:

```
create or replace TRIGGER MY_TIGGER_NAME   AFTER UPDATE ON MY_TABLE 
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW  FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN ( NEW.STATUS = ANY (10,40,42,44,46,50,60)  and OLD.STATUS != NEW.STATUS)        
DECLARE
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
   flag NUMBER(1,0) :=0;
BEGIN   
  IF :NEW.ALERT is NULL and flag=0 
  THEN      
    dbms_alert.signal('print_update_event','update_message');
    flag:=1;
  ELSE      
    dbms_alert.signal( :NEW.ALERT,'update_message');
  END IF;    
  commit;
END;
```

Package variable could be used instead local variable but I think that package variable is bad idea because two triggers can be executed in parallel. Maybe I am wrong.

I attach diagram of trigger which shows what I would like to achieve.

[image]
How to do it?

Comment: You can do it using compound trigger, but compund triggers are available starting from Oracle 11.2, What is your database version ?

Comment: Are you sure it is possible? Where should the trigger know from, whether it is the same update? There could be more user than one that updates rows. Maybe you should take time as criteria. And I think you need a table instead of a local variable.

Comment: My Oracle database version is 9 and higher.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm#526 -   **If you specify FOR EACH ROW, then the trigger fires once for each row of the table that is affected by the triggering statement. The absence of the FOR EACH ROW option indicates that the trigger fires only once for each applicable statement, but not separately for each row affected by the statement.** In general - avoid Triggers as much as possible, instead, try to find the program that does the updates and at the end of it execution, call the alert.